# Run validation on 1 GPU while Train on multi-GPU Pytorch Lightning

Tags: pytorch-lightning

Is there any way I can execute `validation_step` method on single GPU while `training_step` with multiple GPU using DDP.

The reason I want to do is because there are several metrics which I want to implement which requires complete access to the data, and running on single GPU will ensure that. I have tried `validation_step_end` method but somehow I am only getting part of the data. That post is here: [Stack Overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64920956/validation-epoch-end-with-ddp-pytorch-lightning/65005246#65005246)

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that this is not possible. But there is the [TorchMetrics](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package which has been developed with multi-GPU support in mind so when your [custom metric](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#implementing-a-metric) is derived from TM you shall be able to get running even on your multi-GPU setting.

Comment: Yes if you use TorchMetrics you should be able to achieve what you are trying to achomplish